# Does it negatively impact performance to use a function returning a boolean in ngIf directives?

Tags: angular

What I mean is this:

```js
// my.component.ts
// ...
public isVisible() {
  myObject.nested.prop > 27 && otherObj.foo === 'lala'
}
```

And then in the template:

```html
// my.component.html
<div *ngIf="isVisible()">
  <p>Hi!</p>
</div>
```

The function doesn't do anything crazy so it's cheap to run but I want it to be a function instead of a variable so that is updates the boolean as the values it checks change. If I don't use a function but a variable (either as a boolean or as a `BehaviorSubject<boolean>`), I'm getting the infamous `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

I tried running the profiler in the browser and having the function logging to the console whenever it runs and while it runs several times in a row it didn't seem to have much impact.

Is this bad practice? Does it have an impact on performance vs using a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling a function in template is a bad practice, because how many times that function will be called will depend upon number of change detection cycles. Number of change detection cycles depends upon feature you implement.

We should generally avoid calling of function of templates. Instead what you can do is create a pipe and pass input to pipe to return desired value. Pipes are pure by default, so they will only be called if input changes.

To know more in detail you can refer :- https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to the `ngIf` will be run every time the change detector runs.

If the function is extremely simple and short, there shouldn't be a performance issue, but if it's more than just a simple getter, I'd advise you to bind to a variable instead and update that variable when necessary (probably through a subscription to an `Observable`).